# DllMain already defined in dllmain.obj

Tags: c++, atl

I have an ATL Project, it worked perfectly when I build it for X86 system, but when I tried to build it for X64 the following fatal error shows:

"Error  LNK2005 DllMain already defined in dllmain.obj"

Answer (score 0):

User the linker /verbose option to find the modules where DllMain is defined.
Also you can see in this list who requests to insert this module into the linked modules.

Also it may be good to check the general project settings.